# What should I do if a texture formatted BC3_UNORM don't have a resolution multiple of 4?

Tags: directx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiBn3.png)

I have a texture of which resolution is 95x90 and format is DXGI_FORMAT_BC3_UNORM.
I try to load this texture but get an error below.

D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D: A Texture2D created with the following Format (0x4d, BC3_UNORM) experiences aligment restrictions on the dimensions of the Resource. The dimensions, which are (Width: 95, Height: 90), must be multiples of (Width: 4, Height: 4). [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #101: CREATETEXTURE2D_INVALIDDIMENSIONS]

It makes no sense that I open the Painter apps and resize the original texture.
Is there nice way to fix this error?

+

If I load the texture using Visual Studio, it has dimension multiply of 4.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPTFr.png)

It is different when I load the texture with DirectX Tex.

```
auto hr = DirectX::CreateDDSTextureFromFile(Graphic::Device(), path.data(), &_texture, &_srv);
```

Comment: I used DirectX Texture Tool, and resized to make res multiple of 4. I don't know whether to resize it corrupts my compressed image data but it' works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formal rules of DirectX is that BC compressed images must have a multiple of 4 for the 'top-level' image width & height, but mipmaps can obviously result in non-multiple-of-4 values. There are also special rules for dealing with 1x1, 1x2, 2x1, and 2x2 pixel cases.

[DirectXTex](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex) can block-compress artibrary sized images to support mipmaps.

I have a `-fixbc4x4:`switch in my [texconv](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/Texconv) tool specifically for this case. It 'resizes' the top-most mip level without a decompression/compression cycle, but it will lose any mip levels so if you want to regenerate them you'll end up decompressing/compressing for that.

So in short this will create a version of the DDS texture with just the top-most level rounded up to 4x4 multiples without any modification of the blocks.

```
texconv -fixbc4x4 -m 1 inputdds.dds
```

This will fix the top-most level without any modifications of the blocks, decompress the image, generate mips, and then recompress.

```
texconv -fixbc4x4 -m 0 inputdds.dds
```