# How can a block compressed image always have a first mip level that's a multiple of 4?

Tags: graphics, directx, vulkan

In DirectX according to the rules the topmost mip (the most detailed), needs to be a multiple of 4:

```
The formal rules of DirectX is that BC compressed images must have a multiple of 4 for the 'top-level' image width & height, but mipmaps can obviously result in non-multiple-of-4 values.
```

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66601094/what-should-i-do-if-a-texture-formatted-bc3-unorm-dont-have-a-resolution-multip) to Stack Overflow answer.

> Note that Direct3D will not allow a resource to be created using BC format with the top-level size set to something other than a multiple of 4 in width and height, even though it does allow the mipchain below it to not meet that requirement.

From another source. However my understanding is that Vulkan does not have this requirement. My question is, you clearly don't want to have the highest mip-level loaded in cases where you can unload it and use a lower detailed texture. So then I decide to load a lower mip level as the topmost level, but it's not a multiple of 4, does this mean I can't use that mip level as the topmost level? What are you supposed to do?

Comment: Are you using sparse textures here?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas No, no sparse textures.

Comment: Then how do you do this: "*you clearly don't want to have the highest mip-level loaded in cases where you can unload it and use a lower detailed texture*"? Sparse textures are the only way I know of to snip off part of a texture. Are you creating two textures?

Comment: @NicolBolas No, I have a mipmapped texture, but if a high level mip isn't being used, for reason that it's being far away from the camera, then why have the highest mip loaded in memory given that it's not being used? So you start off with 2048 texture, then the object you're rendering is small, and the higher mips aren't used, then you should create a new image starting at a smaller size, no?

Comment: "*then you should create a new image starting at a smaller size, no?*" That kind of shuffling around of allocations would cause fragmentation of your memory space. And again, that's the point of sparse textures: it's a way of handling this circumstance *without* fragmenting allocations. You simply free up the blocks that underlay the higher mipmap levels without messing with the actual `VkImage` itself.

Comment: @NicolBolas Do many gpus support sparse textures??

Comment: From what I can see, [sparse residency seems pretty popular](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/listdevicescoverage.php?feature=sparseResidencyImage2D), at least among desktop GPUs. Hardly a surprise, given that [some form of sparse binding predates Vulkan itself](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_sparse_texture.txt).

Comment: @NicolBolas Sparse residency gets complicated, I have trouble maintaining code with thousands of different combinations of how to do things. Let's say when I generate the mip levels I round up or down to a multiple of 4. Will that make them a mismatch with what Vulkan expects? Given that it probably assumes original_size / 2 rounded to integer?

Comment: Without considering sparse residency, it’s not uncommon to load texture starting from the n-th mipmap. I don’t have enough practice to be authoritative on this but the Vulkan spec seems to include padding without any restriction for the main mipmap: https://registry.khronos.org/DataFormat/specs/1.3/dataformat.1.3.html https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkImageCreateInfo.html
That being said, I always work with power of two images so I never think about padding

Comment: @GuillaumeGris Yes but it's not conformant with other graphics APIs. What are you supposed to do when using block compression, which you pretty much always should, and want to load a lower mipmap, which you almost always should be wanting to do, especially at the most detailed mipmaps a difference of 1 or 2 mip levels is millions of pixels of data sitting in your VRAM that doesn't need to be there.

Comment: @Zebrafish When I had to do this with DX11 a few years ago, I just did not optimize such textures. I logged a warning in the asset validation log stating the texture was not a power of 2 and this prevented some memory optimization. Then we went to the art team and asked them to redo the texture. You can always use UV coordinates to use a non power of 2 subsection of a power of 2 texture

Comment: @GuillaumeGris You start off with a texture with a width of 28, It's a multiple of four meaning it can be used with block compression as the first image.  The next mip of that lower is 14. Now, the BC and DirectX rules say that you can't create an image with that size as the top level mip. Meaning you can't do mip optimisation (evicting higher mips) at all. Eventually for a non pot texture you get to a non-multiple of 4. You can't create the mip chain as / 2 rounded up to multiple of 4, because that's not what the API expects and it'll break everything.

Comment: My meaning is: rather than trying to optimize such situations, consider that there is an issue with the data, don’t optimize this kind of data, add ways to detect missed optimization opportunities and stick to pot textures. If you still want to do this optimization for non pot textures in a portable way, I don’t have the answer to this question

Answer (score 2):

When Direct3D first added support for Block-Compressed formats (i.e. DXTn), the API enforced that the top-most level of the texture must have width and height dimensions which were multiples of 4. Over time, it became apparent that hardware had to handle smaller blocks like 1x1, 2x1, 1x2, 2x2, 4x1, 4x2, 2x4 in order to deal with mipmap chains.

As such, modern video hardware supports non-multiple-of-4 block compressed surfaces anyhow, it's just the Direct3D API that enforced the multiple-of-4 on top-level textures. In fact lots of drivers will accept arbitrary sizes without complaint, and only the Direct3D Debug Layer would flag the violation.

With Direct3D 12, the `D3D12_FEATURE_DATA_D3D12_OPTIONS8.UnalignedBlockTexturesSupported` optional feature indicates if the driver officially supports non-multiple-of-4 BC top-most textures.

Comment: Wow, everything's a mess, it took my 3 days to get this answer, thank you.  There's no way you can do mip stream if you don't hold to the strict requirement f using pot textures. At some point you'll have a mip level which isn't multiple of 4 and you'll want to use that as the top-most texture because that resolution of texture is all you need. And with this strict requirement that's not possible. How are you supposed to do mip streaming without some convoluted virtual texturing solution?